# CV skill bar with text on the left side

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, bar

I have the following example:

```
\newcounter{yval}
\newenvironment{bardiagram}
    {
        \setcounter{yval}{0}
        \newcommand{\skill}[2]{
            \filldraw[lightgray] (0,\value{yval}) rectangle (10,\value{yval}+0.4);
            \shade[fill=white,left color = white, right color=red](0,\value{yval}+0.4) rectangle (##1, \value{yval});
            \stepcounter{yval}
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    }
    {
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
```

The code produces the following output:
[image: Diagramm]

I like to have the following result, but I do not know how to get it:

[image: wanted result]

I have already tried to position a node in the rectangle, but I think it is not the right approach.

Thanks for helping!

---

**Edit:** 
I've already tried to make a tabular, but the text is shifted very strange then.

Comment: It's very difficult try to find a solution, because your code it's not compilable. I think that if you change `\filldraw[lightgray] (0,\value{yval}) rectangle (10,\value{yval}+0.4);` with `\filldraw[lightgray] (0,\value{yval})node[left] {text} rectangle (10,\value{yval}+0.4);` should work.

Comment: It shows the text a little below the wished position, but nevertheless thank you.

Comment: If you want raise the node of 1pt add the key `yshift=1pt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have something where the bars always start at the same horizontal position for each diagram, and extend to the east side of the text area.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\newcounter{yval}
\newenvironment{bardiagram}
    {
        \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \setcounter{yval}{0}
        \newcommand{\Skill}[2]{\stepcounter{yval}
        \ifnum\value{yval}=1
         \node[align=left,font=\sffamily] (n-\number\value{yval}){##1};       
         \edef\LstSkills{##2}
         \edef\LstNodes{(n-\number\value{yval})}
        \else
         \node[align=left,font=\sffamily,anchor=north west] (n-\number\value{yval})
          at ([yshift=-1ex]n-\the\numexpr\value{yval}-1\relax.south west)
          {##1};          
         \edef\LstSkills{\LstSkills,##2}
         \edef\LstNodes{\LstNodes (n-\number\value{yval})}
        \fi
        }
    }
    {
         \node[fit=\LstNodes,inner sep=0pt] (aux){};
         \foreach \X [count=\Y] in \LstSkills
         {\path[overlay,fill=lightgray] let 
         \p1=($(current page text area.east)-(aux.east)$) in 
         ([xshift=\x1*\X/10]n-\Y.south-|aux.east) rectangle 
          (n-\Y.north-|current page text area.east);
          \draw[overlay,left color = white, right color=red] let 
         \p1=($(current page text area.east)-(aux.east)$) in 
         ([xshift=\x1*\X/10]n-\Y.south-|aux.east) rectangle 
          (n-\Y.north-|aux.east);}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{bardiagram}
 \Skill{Hibernating}{4}
 \Skill{Purring}{9}
 \Skill{Preparing\\ espresso}{3}
\end{bardiagram}
\bigskip

\begin{bardiagram}
 \Skill{Using Ti\emph{k}Z}{6}
 \Skill{Elementary geometry}{8}
 \Skill{Writing and spelling}{2}
\end{bardiagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks very nice, thank you very much!:)